# Magento reindexing table

Tags: magento

I am updating the product information like quantity,shippingindays,outofstock values etc through mysql and the value gets updated but unless reindexing is done, it is not reflecting in the frontend.What to do to make the reflection in front end instantaneously or can i update the reindexing table directly, is it a good practise to do that? and also if the product goes out of stock how this reflection is instantaneous??

Answer (score 0):

Try this code when you load the frontend to reindex everything. You can check the run method inside Mage file for getSingleton and all.

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php';  
$app = Mage::app('default');  

$indexingProcesses = Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->getProcessesCollection(); 
foreach ($indexingProcesses as $process) {
      $process->reindexEverything();
}
```

Hope this may help.